# vscode: changing a file modifies it in temp folder, I cannot make changes to files outside of the temp folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a file built by somebody else. I am trying to append lines to the end of it.

When I do this and hit save, everything seems to work. But the only change has been in the temp folder, which seems to be a copy of my real folder. No changes occur to  the actual file. This means that I cannot do development in vscode, since I cannot actually modify files.

How can I fix this?